# Is it ideal to scan package-lock.json in veracode?

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, package.json, veracode, package-lock.json

in my react app , i have integrated veracode. In the scan reports it is picking up the libraries from package-lock.json and showing it as high vulnerability.While those packages are in latest version in package.json. Some of the libraries in package-lock.json requires the previous versions of libraries , like this

```
Invalid: lock file's lodash@4.17.4 does not satisfy lodash@4.17.15
```

Is there anyway to fix the lock file version number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to scan `package-lock.json` for any vulnerabilities since it takes the precedence while installing `node_modules` for your `production` environment. Have you tried deleting `package-lock.json`, generation again with `npm install` and committing new/updated `package-lock.json`?

Comment: yes i have regenerated the package-lock.json. But the version number is not yet updated

Comment: Try deleting `package-lock.json`, `lodash` folder in `node_modules` and do `npm install`.